# Как правильно разделить строку?

Tags: java, android, строки

Как разделить строку от известного знака и до ее конца?

При работе с `zip` файлом у меня есть такой метод

```
ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
String str = ze.getName();
```

и в итоге в строке `str` храниться вот такое значение `**dirName**/**fileName**.**extention**`

Мне нужно отрезать `**dirName**`, чтоб получить `/**fileName**.**extention**`

То есть символ `/` и все что после него...

Те методы которые я придумал (такие как разложить на массив и уже из него методом проверок удалять то, что не нужно и т.д.), мне кажутся уж очень через голову.

Пролистал все стандартные методы `String` и там тоже ничего подходящего не нашел.

Хотя понимаю, что задача простая(

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как насчет того, чтобы использовать `substring`?

```
String fileName = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, str.length());
```

Comment: Да спасибо! Это работает... Я там накрутил через `split("/");`, но ваш вариант явно короче